# What's the relationship between thyrohyoid membrane and medial thyrohyoid ligament? Are they distinct structures or are fused together?

Tags: practice-of-medicine, anatomy, otolaryngology, ligament

I'm studying the anatomy of the larynx and I can't understand If larynx ligaments such as medial or lateral thyrohyoid ligaments are fused with the membrane or not.

Comment: Hi Francesca, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this saves us from reiterating obvious answers and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with a reference to the textbook you are studying from or links to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: What's the difference between a ligament and a membrane? [That's a tough one](https://teachmeanatomy.info/neck/viscera/larynx/ligaments-folds/) when it comes to the laryngeal ligaments (pun intended).